# wp_kses and magic quotes

Tags: php, wp-kses

In the [wp_kses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) codex page it says:

> You have to remove any slashes from PHP's magic quotes before you call
>   this function.

I am new(ish) to PHP and I wiki'd Magic Quotes and it was apparently recently deprecated/removed from the language. So is this something that I still have to worry about?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is still adding slashes to data sent per POST, so yes, in some cases you might have to remove the slashes. There are two options:

1. Use `stripslashes_deep( $value )`. This function accepts an array, an object or a string and removes the slashes.
2. Get POST data per:

   ```
   $data = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
   ```

   This takes the data from the raw input stream, a resource that cannot be changed (read-only), so it is not changed by WordPress too. This doesn’t work when the form was sent with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, eg. with file uploads.

Be aware `stripslashes_deep()` might ruin JSON encoded strings.

[Magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are not quotes, they are backslashes `\`. They work like [`addslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) and are applied on several places to incoming data. Backslashes are set before `'`, `"`, `\` and the character `NULL`.

In WordPress there is a function `add_magic_quotes()` (`wp-includes/functions.php`). It runs on `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` and `$_SERVER` in `wp-includes/load.php` in the function `wp_magic_quotes()`, and on user/post data pulled from the database.

Comment: What exactly are PHP magic quotes?  Do you have an example of when they might be added?

Comment: @William See my update.